# AWS Lambda, Python and SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, lambda, pymssql

I am getting quite confused on how to approach connecting to SQL server from a Python Lambda function. At this point, I am just trying to connect to my SQL Server (Azure) instance from the [recommended AMI image](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/current-supported-versions.html) .

The first and most popular approach seems to be using pymssql.  Within that, it seems like you can go with the precompiled FreeTDS version (`export PYMSSQL_BUILD_WITH_BUNDLED_FREETDS=1`) or you can install FreeTDS on your system.

I have tried both and always ended up with the following error:

```
>>> pymssql.connect('myserver.database.windows.net', 'myuser@myserver.database.windows.net', 'mypass', 'mydb')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "pymssql.pyx", line 641, in pymssql.connect (pymssql.c:10824)
pymssql.OperationalError: (20002, 'DB-Lib error message 20002, severity 9:\nAdaptive Server connection failed (myserver.database.windows.net:1433)\n')
```

Note, that if I install FreeTDS on the system and attempt to connect with `tsql`, I have no problems at all.

I can provide more info on exactly how my installs are setup if someone can help me with this approach.  Alternatively, I am happy to go the pyodbc route but would need some help in that direction, too.

Update:

I tried going the pyodbc route and managed to get the drivers installed following this [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017).  Will update on future progress

Comment: Not really helpful to your current position - Ive had success using pyodbc.  Why do you need\want to use it as a lamda function though?

Comment: @Jaberwocky I want to update the database when a new file arrives in S3.  S3 has the capability to call a Lambda function when a new file arrives.